Inverted circular bottom right border
I'm a beginner in Flutter and I need an inverted circular bottom right border.
I'm trying to achieve this:

I've tried to Clip, but i dont really don't understand how it works.
Here is what I could get:

With this code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Folder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final Widget child;

  const Folder({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bgColor = backgroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
    final titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium;

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(title, style: titleStyle),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0), child: child),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}



you can do it with custom painter

It worked! Thanks!!

mind showing the code that worked?
